# What's the difference between &inode->i_data and inode->i_mapping

Tags: linux-kernel

I found in most cases, i_data is just the dereferenced data of i_mapping like below, why set two same value in the one inode structure ?

```
crash> struct inode ffffffc073c1f360 -o
struct inode {
 ...
  [ffffffc073c1f4a8] struct file_lock *i_flock;
  **[ffffffc073c1f4b0] struct address_space i_data;**
  [ffffffc073c1f558] struct list_head i_devices;
 ...   

crash> struct inode ffffffc073c1f360
struct inode {
...
  i_op = 0xffffffc0007ad1c0 <ext4_file_inode_operations>, 
  i_sb = 0xffffffc002010000, 
  **i_mapping = 0xffffffc073c1f4b0,** 
  i_security = 0xffffffc07230d050, 
...
```

Answer (score 6):

Address space always deals with page cache. While accessing a page in page cache if the owner of the page is file, the `address_space` object is embedded in the `i_data` field of VFS inode object. The i_mapping field of inode always points to `address_space` object of the owner of the pages containing the inode's data. The host field of the `address_space` object points to the inode object in which the descriptor is embedded.

E.g. if page belongs to a regular file that is stored in ext4 filesystem, the `i_data` of VFS inode points to inode of that file and i_mapping field of inode points to `i_data` of same inode, and the host field of `address_space` object points to the same inode.

However things are not that simple always. Suppose a page contains data read from block device file, which contains "raw" data of a block device, the `address_space` is embedded in the "master" inode of the file in the bdev, special filesystem associated with the block device(referenced by bd_inode). Hence the i_mapping field of the inode of block device file points to the
`address_space` object embedded in the master inode;correspondingly the host field of `address_space` object points to the master inode. In this way, all pages containing data read from block device have same `address_space` object, even if they have been accessed by referring to different block device files.
So there is slight distinction between the two when it come to page belongs to regular file or to block device special file.

Answer (score 0):

From http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0105.2/1363.html:

> i_data is "pages read/written by this inode"
>
> i_mapping is "whom should I ask for pages?"
>
> IOW, everything outside of individual filesystems should use the latter.
>   They are same if (and only if) inode owns the data. CODA (or anything that
>   caches data on a local fs) will have i_mapping pointing to the i_data of
>   inode it caches into. Ditto for block devices if/when they go into pagecache -
>   we should associate pagecache with struct block_device, since we can have
>   many inodes with the same major:minor. IOW, ->i_mapping should be pointing
>   to the same place for all of them.

From https://marc.info/?l=linux-fsdevel&m=99470104708354&w=2:

> It is used by filesystems that wrap around existing ones. AFAIK Coda is
>   the only one in the tree that actually uses this.
>
> All VFS functions always use inode->i_mapping->a_ops. Coda copies the
>   i_mapping of the underlying inode to it's own inode. This way we use the
>   same address space as the container file and avoid mapping the same file
>   pages in different locations in memory.

i_mapping is the true page cache. i_data is where an address_space resides and is allocated and freed with the inode, and is normally where i_mapping points to. But a filesystem can leave the i_data of an inode empty and points the i_mapping to the i_data of another inode, to avoid multiple page caches.